# Foreign key error in django, Cannot assign "'1'": "Release.projectID" must be a "Project" instance

Tags: django

I have two models: 'Project' and 'Release'.
In release table, projectId is foreign key associated with Project table.
When tried creating new release, when entered projectID, getting:

```
Cannot assign "'1'": "Release.projectID" must be a "Project" instance
```

I have three files named, models.py, forms.py,views.py

```
models.py:

class Project(models.Model):
        JIRAID = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True)
        projectID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        projectName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        projectDescription = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        projectStartDate = models.DateField()
        projectEndDate = models.DateField()
        projectEstimatedLOE = models.IntegerField()
        createdBy = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        createdAt = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now,null=True,blank=True)
        updatedAt = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now,null=True,blank=True)

        def __str__(self):
                return (self.JIRAID, self._get_pk_val, self.projectName, self.projectDescription, self.projectStartDate, self.projectEndDate, self.projectEstimatedLOE,self.createdBy,self.createdAt,self.updatedAt)


        class Meta:
                db_table='Project'

class Release(models.Model):
        JIRAID = models.CharField(max_length=20 )
        projectID = models.ForeignKey(Project,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
        releaseID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        releaseName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        releaseDescription = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        releaseStartDate = models.DateField()
        releaseEndDate = models.DateField()
        releaseEstimatedLOE = models.IntegerField()
        createdBy = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        createdAt = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now, null=True, blank=True)
        updatedAt = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now, null=True, blank=True)

        def __str__(self):
                return (self.JIRAID, self.projectID,self._get_pk_val,self.releaseName, self.releaseDescription, self.releaseStartDate, self.releaseEndDate, self.releaseEstimatedLOE,self.createdBy,self.createdAt,self.updatedAt)


        class Meta:
                db_table='Release'
                unique_together = (('projectID', 'releaseID'),)


Views.py:

def releasecreation(request):
    context = {'form': Release}
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = ReleaseCreationForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            JIRAID=request.POST.get('JIRAID')
            projectID=Project.objects.get('projectID')
            releaseID=request.POST.get('releaseID')
            releaseName=request.POST.get('releaseName')
            releaseDescription=request.POST.get('releaseDescription')
            releaseStartDate=request.POST.get('releaseStartDate')
            releaseEndDate=request.POST.get('releaseEndDate')
            releaseEstimatedLOE=request.POST.get('releaseEstimatedLOE')
            createdBy = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
            form.save()

            return render(request,'releasepages/releasecreateconfirmation.html')
        else:
            return render(request,'releasepages/releasecreate.html')
    else:
        return render(request,'releasepages/releasecreate.html',context)
```

I should be able to create release,by getting dropdown at projectID column while creating release.

Comment: Show us code for the form?

Comment: `class ReleaseCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    JIRAID=forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    projectID = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    releaseID = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    releaseName=forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    releaseDescription=forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    releaseStartDate=forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget())
    releaseEndDate=forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget())
    releaseEstimatedLOE= forms.IntegerField()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
projectID=Project.objects.filter(pk=request.POST.get('projectID')).first()
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks ! But it is still not working, same error.

Comment: Actually i don't want to enter a value in projectID while creating Release, i should be getting dropdown of available projectID's.

Answer (score 0):

There is a few things that is not quite right with this code:

- setting form *class* in the context

  The template probably expects a form instance and not a class, like: `{'form': Release()}` (note the parenthesis).

  Also, is it on purpose that this is not the same class as `ReleaseCreationForm` used below?
- defining a bunch of variables and never using them

  Unless there is some removed code, I don't see any usage for all those variables defined right after `if form.is_valid():`.
- do a http redirect after for save

  When a form has been successfully saved, the application should issue a redirect instead of rendering a template. This is to prevent resubmitting the form if user decides to reload the page.

I suggest closely following the view structure from here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/#the-view
This has all the "ifs" needed to process a form and they are in exactly the correct structure. If tempted to alter this logic, I would be very very cautions that I'm doing something wrong.

---

But to answer your question directly, to (manually) create an instance of `Release`, you can do one of these two things:

```
project_instance = Project.objects.get(projectID=123)
Release.objects.create(
    projectID=project_instance,
    # other_fields...
)
```

or

```
Release.objects.create(
    projectID_id=123,
    # other_fields...
)
```

As you can see, `ForeignKey` field automatically creates another attribute on the model that has `_id` appended to it (so you have both `projectID` and `projectID_id` attributes on your `Release` model). Accessing `release_instance.projectID` will return an instance of `Project` model and **not** its ID.

This is probably not as intended, and I'm guessing that it would be cleaner to rename the model field `projectID` into `project`.

Comment: Thanks for revert, but Release don't have projectID and projectID_id fields, DJango automatically renames projectID to projectID_id when I am keeping it as foreign key.

Comment: @Vidya The _DB table_ should only have `projectID_id` column and no `projectID` column, but the model instances (i.e. objects in Python) should have both attributes: `projectID_id` (an int) and `projectID` (an instance of `Project`).

Comment: Ohh! So you are saying, in views.py I should have projectID_id and projectID values? but at the end in the form i will be giving only one value through front end.